# How to push a vector to an action

Tags: smart-contract, action

I'm troubled with a problem about how I can use command line `cleos push action` to push a vector to an already existing action, such as:

void vectortest(const std::vector &vec) ;

Anyone who can help me? Thanks

Comment: did you try `cleos push action <contract> <action> '["arg1", ["vec_elem1", "vec_elem2"]]' -p <account>` assuming the second param is the vector

Comment: @confused00 thanks for your comment.I'd try to use your fomat,but failed,and the error message is string_type convert to json failed.

Comment: I think you need to define the type of vector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

suppose your action looks like this:
first define type of your vector let say you need a vector of double

```
void vectortest(const std::vector<double> &vec) ;
```

than you should be able to call like this:

```
cleos push action your_account vectortest '{"vec":[1.2,2.5,4.6]}' -p your_account
```

your_account is the account with which you set your contract.

Comment: This does not work for me. 
I get this response: 
2018-10-07T04:25:26.099 thread-0   http_plugin.cpp:476           handle_exception     ] Exception Details: 3050000 action_validate_exception: Action validate exception
Unknown action pgram in contract blackjack
    {"action":"pgram","contract":"blackjack"}
    thread-0  chain_plugin.cpp:1564 abi_json_to_bin
code: blackjack, action: pgram, args: {"player_cards":[3,4,5,6]}
    {"code":"blackjack","action":"pgram","args":{"player_cards":[3,4,5,6]}}
    thread-0  chain_plugin.cpp:1575 abi_json_to_bin

Comment: Did you imported the vector library ,if you does Can you please share the code